# How can I see which i686 instructions are faster

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, osdev, micro-optimization

As the title says, I want to see which i686 instructions are faster, how can I see?

Example: is adding to a register faster or moving a value to a reg faster?

Comment: It does not make much sense to discuss performance at this level these days, especially when the two things compared do different things.

Comment: Read a microarchitectural table, such as those provided by Agner Fog.

Comment: Do you mean https://www.agner.org/optimize/ as the microarchitectural table provided my Agner Fog?

Comment: For your example of whether `mov reg,reg` can be faster than `add reg,reg`, see [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44193770) - yes, it surprisingly can be faster (but never free).  `mov` is special.  In general, see also the links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info  (But yes, Agner Fog's microarch and asm guides are definitely the place to start.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've read the begining of the pdfs from https://www.agner.org/optimize/, it is a pretty good source, there are in total 5 pdfs including cpp and asm optimization and instruction speed